# Choppy audio under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

I did a fresh install (I was running Ubuntu 18.04 prior to the new install) of Ubuntu 20.04 on my Toshiba Satellite C875. Now the audio (any audio) is choppy (words or parts of words get repeated at random.) This is my audio card information:

```
*-multimedia--
             --description: Audio device--
             --product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller--
             --vendor: Intel Corporation--
             --physical id: 1b--
             --bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0--
             --version: 04--
             --width: 64 bits--
             --clock: 33MHz--
             --capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list--
             --configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0--
             --resources: irq:32 memory:c2510000-c2513fff--
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this phenomenon?